# Groovy: Idiomatic way to replace captured groups

Tags: java, regex, groovy, regex-group

I've a string like this: `docker login -u username -p password docker-registry-url`.

I execute the command in a Groovy script with `execute`. For debugging purposes, I print the command before execution, but since it contains sensitive data, I obfuscate the username and password.

```
def printableCmd = cmd.toString()

def m = printableCmd =~ /(?:.+) -u (.+) -p (.+) (?:.+)/

if (m.matches() && m[0].size() >= 3) {
  printableCmd = m[0][-1..-2].inject(m[0][0]) { acc, val -> acc.replaceAll(val, "***") }
}
```

The above works as expected and prints `docker login -u *** -p *** docker-registry-url`, but I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to do this. Note that I don't want to delete the captured groups, just replace them with asterisks, thus making it very clear that the command is not wrong, but obfuscated for security purposes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
def cmd='docker login -u username -p password docker-registry-url'
println cmd.replaceAll(/(\s-[up]\s+)(\S+)/,'$1***')
```

Output:

```
docker login -u *** -p *** docker-registry-url
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution myself using positive look-behind:

```
​def cmd = "docker login -u username -p password docker-registry-url"
println cmd.replaceAll(/(?<=-[up]\s)(\S+)/,"***")
```

Comment: If there are 2 or more spaces between `-u` and  1+ non-whitespace chars, your lookbehind approach will fail. Capturing group approach is the correct one. You might use `/(?<=-[up]\s{1,100})(\S+)/`, but it is rather a hacky feature in a Java regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perhaps you are referring to the fact that look-behind in java has to be of known length, so \s+ wouldn't work. I used \s{1,10} instead. The reason I prefer this over daggett's answer is because, IMO, it expresses the requirement clearer.